# POSTGRESQL: The id is incrementing 4, 6 on creation instead of 1

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query in Postgres and if it's an 'insert', the id is not incrementing sequentially. I ran this query once and I got a row in the table with id=1. I deleted that row and ran the query again and got the id=2. That's fine.

But after that, I didn't delete the row but ran the query. I still had the same row in the table. and then after deleting the row and re-executing the query, I got the id=4, instead of 3.

Now, I ran the query 3 times without deleting the row and after deleting and executing again, I got the id=8.

It looks like it's incrementing the id on the table but the existing row remains same. And then creating a new row, it gets that incremented id.

What is the problem with this query?

```
WITH ins AS (
  INSERT INTO "table" (user_id, length) VALUES (1, 100) ON CONFLICT (user_id) DO NOTHING RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM ins UNION ALL SELECT * FROM "table" WHERE user_id = '${data.user_id}' -- only executed if no INSERT
LIMIT 1
```

```
Table:
id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
length INTEGER DEFAULT 0
```

PostgreSQL: 15.2
RDS Aurora with: POSTGRESQL

Comment: that inserts are not allowed You can SELECT DELETE and UPDATE

Comment: 1) This `only executed if no INSERT` is wrong. The SELECT will execute every time you run the CTE. 2)  The INSERT ... ON CONFLICT will advance the sequence behind the `id` serial field every time an insert is attempted and converted into an update. To verify do `select * from "table"_id_seq`.

Comment: @nbk I am trying to upsert a document.

Comment: Not to the incrementing sequence. See [Create sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html) *Notes ... Because nextval and setval calls are never rolled back, sequence objects cannot be used if “gapless” assignment of sequence numbers is needed. It is possible to build gapless assignment by using exclusive locking of a table containing a counter; but this solution is much more expensive than sequence objects, especially if many transactions need sequence numbers concurrently.*.

Comment: Well I botched that explanation. Providing `VALUES (1, 100)` means the `DEFAULT`(the sequence) for the `id` column won't be needed and therefore the sequence won't be incremented. The only explanation i can think of to explain it is some other process is adding rows to the table and not specifying the `id` value and so the sequence is being incremented outside the ON CONFLICT or an INSERT is being done with no `id` value provided and an ON CONFLICT clause.